# How to use =~ in bash

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal

I am trying to learn how to use re-match opreator in bash, if I understood it well search for a string inside of a string returns true if the string has the substring, i tried:

```
Hello='Hello sr' ; if [[ "$Hello" =~ *Hello*. ]] ; then echo '"Hello" does have the word or sentence "Hello" inside' ; else echo '"Hello" does not have the word or sentence "Hello" inside ' ; fi
```

Or

```
if [[ "$Hello" =~ *Hello*. ]]  
 then 
  echo '"Hello" does has the word or sentence "Hello" inside'
 else
  echo '"Hello" does not have the word or sentence "Hello" inside '
fi
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: `if [[ "$Hello" =~ .*Hello.* ]]` or even `if [[ $Hello =~ Hello ]]`

Comment: The problem is that regexp does not search "string inside a string": it can do that, but in reality it does pattern matching, which is much more powerful (and complicated).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your matching pattern.

`.*` matches 0 or more (`*`) of the character `.`, which matches any character except newline. Now you need to replace `*Hello*.` with `.*Hello.*`.

```
Hello='Hello sr' ; if [[ "$Hello" =~ .*Hello.* ]] ; then echo '"Hello" does has the word or sentence "Hello" inside' ; else echo '"Hello" doesn'"'"'t has the word or sentence "Hello" inside ' ; fi
```

I really like the page https://regexr.com/, because it has the cheatsheet in the sidebar and also explains your matching pattern in the bottom. With this you can learn a lot about your pattern and find bugs more easily.